# Does Gaussian discriminant analysis and linear discriminant analysis refer the same algorithm?

Tags: classification, terminology, linear, discriminant-analysis

I'm pretty new to LDA and I came across other terminology called Gaussian discriminant analysis elsewhere.

Since LDA assumes the normality or normal distribution of the data which is same as Gaussian distribution. Are they both referring to the same algorithm?

Comment: Probably "Gaussian DA" = Linear DA + Quadratic DA, I guess.

Comment: @ttnphns thx, but QDA doesn't assume Gaussian distribution right?

Comment: QDA doesn't assume equal variance-covariance matrices for classes.

Comment: @ttnphns http://cs229.stanford.edu/notes/cs229-notes2.pdf does Gaussian discriminant analysis in this notes referring to linear discriminant analysis?

Comment: I believe in this paper they discuss just LDA.